# How to configure Service URL in Electron while creating build?

Tags: electron

I am migrating existing Silverlight application in Electron and I have used existing WCF service in Electron which alredy used in silverlight app. While deploying Electron application it build .exe setup file and WCF service url is bind with .exe setup file. So I need to deploy separate .exe build for different clients (i.e. different WCF URL). Is there any way in electron to configure the WCF service so there's no need to create a separate build? Any help would be appreciated.